# Add missing unique rows to data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

So I have two data frames that have different lengths. I'm trying to make them have similar lengths by adding the rows from dx that tdx is missing. In this instance, tdx is missing the rows where Age == "UNSP". I have other datasets that might be missing different rows; I'm looking to find a way to identify which rows are missing and then for the output add those rows; the Years column (for that row) would be NA values.

**More clearly the output would be a data frame with the tx and tdx data side-by-side where the Gender and Age match.**

Here's what I have tried (thanks to Richard for pointing out that I forget to add this)

```
(extra <- rbind(dx[8,],dx[16,]))
(extra[,3] <- NA)

ttdx <- rbind(extra,tdx, deparse.level = 1)
```

Then I arranged it back to normal. It works but I'd rather have a more efficient and automated way of doing this (for my other datasets)

If I had a better idea how to identify the differences between the data.frames by the computer, I would probably use `dplyr` or `reshape2` to add the missing rows.

`> head(dx,n = 12L)`

```
   Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13
1  FEMALE   0-2   48020   43120   39120   14360
2  FEMALE   3-9   87930  101850   98750   85400
3  FEMALE 10-19    5700   47730   53590   18800
4  FEMALE 20-39  147230  134560   62090   71120
5  FEMALE 40-59  202770  142230  116120   98830
6  FEMALE 60-64   34980   49170   46260  110120
7  FEMALE   65+  256240  296710  254040  266690
8  FEMALE  UNSP    5500      NA      NA      NA
9    MALE   0-2   75170   52990   28110   32160
10   MALE   3-9   66360   89840   79220   39470
11   MALE 10-19   62960   15060   26700   26310
12   MALE 20-39   39670  145380  101880   94500
```

`> head(tdx, n = 12L)`

```
   Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13
1  FEMALE   0-2   36800   24560   25790   12400
2  FEMALE   3-9   77980   75810   79560   74450
3  FEMALE 10-19    5700   47730   51470   18800
4  FEMALE 20-39  147230  102400   42360   58190
5  FEMALE 40-59  179550  112510  105000   79140
6  FEMALE 60-64   33800   37380   35040   83670
7  FEMALE   65+  206270  202790  185460  225620
8    MALE   0-2   59930   46350   28110   26490
9    MALE   3-9   53260   62770   71350   32380
10   MALE 10-19   60490   15060   25260   20660
11   MALE 20-39   32490  132830   94950   88640
12   MALE 40-59   57950   70370  149790  136730
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use `expand.grid` to make a master list which covers all combinations first, then `merge` your data back against this, e.g.: `master <- expand.grid(a=c("1-2","3-5","5-10"),b=c("f","m","unspec"))`

Comment: You've asked _alot_ of questions on this data set. It might be worth taking the time to learn R a bit more vs getting SO folks to write your program for you.

Comment: @RichardScriven
Oops, I should have explained what I had tried. Bear with me its incredibly inefficient.

I subsetted dx with tdx's missing rows (ie. `(extra <- dx[8,])
(extra[,3] <- NA)`and then using `rbind` I combined tdx with these subsets to make another data.frame. Then I arranged it back to normal. 

It works but I'd rather have a more efficient and automated way of doing this (for my other datasets)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I wish I had the time. Learning R is going to have to be an experiential learning opportunity for me, I apologize if that goes against the SO community guidelines.

Comment: Please make this a reproducible example, by giving actual data for `dx` and `tdx`.  As it is, you are showing only the index columns, so it is impossible to determine what code is needed.  The answer may be as simple as `merge(dx, tdx, all=TRUE)`.

Comment: Hey @MatthewLundberg I tried merge previously but the output is vertical. I want the output to put dx and tdx, side by side because I subtract the value of DX from TDX to produce another column.

Comment: How about `merge(dx, tdx, by=c('Gender','Age'), all=TRUE)` ?

Comment: I suggest that you do two things.  Edit the question again to indicate that this is what you want, a data frame with the `tx` and `tdx` data side-by-side where the `Gender` and `Age` match.  Then, answer it using my suggestion as a basis for your code.  Doing this is likely to get you answers using `dplyr` or `reshape2` (or other) that are more scaleable than `merge`.

Comment: Will do, thank you for help Matt.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working is `merge(dx, tdx, by=c('Gender','Age'), all=TRUE)`

Thank you to Matt.

Comment: Merge works fine, but this is a way of doing it with dplyr `left_join(dx,tdx, by=c('Gender','Age'))`